# Use in product listing negative impact on speed

Tags: attributes, product-attribute, product-list

On our catalog page I use some attribute to display data.
For this I use the option inside the attribute, use in product listing.

I enabled catalog flat data.
I use Lesti FPC with an good server.
Loading time of a catalog is currently 2.54 sec.
But 1.02 sec of that time is waiting time for the page is loaded.

But I do thinks this has a negative impact on the loading speed of a catalog page.

Code I use:

List.phtml

```
        <?php if ($this->getChild('beknopte_specificaties_grid')) : ?>
        <ul class="highlight-list">
            <?php $this->getChild('beknopte_specificaties_grid')->setProduct($_product);?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('beknopte_specificaties_grid', false); ?>
        </ul>
        <?php else: ?>
        <?php echo substr($_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getShortDescription(), 'short_description'),0, 50) ?></b>
        <?php endif;?>
```

Beknopte_specificaties_grid.phtml, we use this for many categories.

```
<?php
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
    $_product = $this->getProduct();
    $theme = $this->helper('ultimo');
?>

<!-- LAPTOPS -->

<?php $yourCatIds = array(27,233,234,235);
$productCats = $_product->getAvailableInCategories();

if (count(array_intersect($yourCatIds,$productCats))) {

    if($_product->getData('i_processor_family_2196_1')) :
    echo '<li><span class="">' . $_product->getAttributeText('i_processor_family_2196_1') . ' ' . $_product->getAttributeText('i_processor_clock_sp_11379_1') . '</span></li>';
    endif;

    if($_product->getData('i_internal_memory_11381_1')) :
    echo '<li><span class="">' . $_product->getAttributeText('i_internal_memory_11381_1') . ' werkgeheugen</span></li>';
    endif;

    if($_product->getData('i_total_storage_capac_3318_1')) :
    echo '<li><span class="">' . $_product->getAttributeText('i_total_storage_capac_3318_1') . ' ' . $_product->getAttributeText('i_storage_media_11441_1') . '</span></li>';
    endif;

}
?>
```

Is there an way to fix this problem or is there a better way of loading attribute data inside the catalog page?

Comment: You should post some code of what you're doing. Without that, nobody can help you.

Comment: @pspahn Sorry, I edit my request.